# How to create an empty DataFrame with a specified schema?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, schema

I want to create on `DataFrame` with a specified schema in Scala. I have tried to use JSON read (I mean reading empty file) but I don't think that's the best practice.

Answer (score 156):

Lets assume you want a data frame with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- k: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v: integer (nullable = false)
```

You simply define schema for a data frame and use empty `RDD[Row]`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{
    StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val schema = StructType(
    StructField("k", StringType, true) ::
    StructField("v", IntegerType, false) :: Nil)

// Spark < 2.0
// sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schema) 
spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schema)
```

PySpark equivalent is almost identical:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("k", StringType(), True), StructField("v", IntegerType(), False)
])

# or df = sc.parallelize([]).toDF(schema)

# Spark < 2.0 
# sqlContext.createDataFrame([], schema)
df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)
```

Using implicit encoders (Scala only) with `Product` types like `Tuple`:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

Seq.empty[(String, Int)].toDF("k", "v")
```

or case class:

```scala
case class KV(k: String, v: Int)

Seq.empty[KV].toDF
```

or

```
spark.emptyDataset[KV].toDF
```

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer - complete, and also useful if you want to reproduce the schema of an existing dataset quickly. I don't know why is it not the accepted one.

Comment: How to create the df with the trait instead of case class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64276952/encoders-productof-a-scala-trait-schema-in-spark

Answer (score 48):

As of Spark 2.0.0, you can do the following.

### Case Class

Let's define a `Person` case class:

```
scala> case class Person(id: Int, name: String)
defined class Person
```

Import `spark` SparkSession implicit `Encoders`:

```
scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._
```

And use SparkSession to create an empty `Dataset[Person]`:

```
scala> spark.emptyDataset[Person]
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Person] = [id: int, name: string]
```

### Schema DSL

You could also use a Schema "DSL" (see **Support functions for DataFrames** in [org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName)).

```
scala> val id = $"id".int
id: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField = StructField(id,IntegerType,true)

scala> val name = $"name".string
name: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField = StructField(name,StringType,true)

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

scala> val mySchema = StructType(id :: name :: Nil)
mySchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(id,IntegerType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true))

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

scala> val emptyDF = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], mySchema)
emptyDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string]

scala> emptyDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hi, the compiler say that `spark.emptyDataset` not exist on my module, How to use it?  there are some (correct) similar to (non-correct) `val df = apache.spark.emptyDataset[RawData]`?

Comment: @PeterKrauss `spark` is the value you create using `SparkSession.builder` not part of `org.apache.spark` package. There are two `spark` names in use. It's the `spark` you have available in `spark-shell` out of the box.

Comment: Thanks Jacek. I corrected: the SparkSession.builder object is *passed as parameter* (seems the best solution) from  first general initialization, now is running.

Comment: Is there a way to create the empty dataframe using trait instead of case class :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64276952/encoders-productof-a-scala-trait-schema-in-spark

Answer (score 5):

Java version to create empty DataSet:

```
public Dataset<Row> emptyDataSet(){

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application")
                .config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> emptyDataSet = spark.createDataFrame(new ArrayList<>(), getSchema());

    return emptyDataSet;
}

public StructType getSchema() {

    String schemaString = "column1 column2 column3 column4 column5";

    List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    StructField indexField = DataTypes.createStructField("column0", DataTypes.LongType, true);
    fields.add(indexField);

    for (String fieldName : schemaString.split(" ")) {
        StructField field = DataTypes.createStructField(fieldName, DataTypes.StringType, true);
        fields.add(field);
    }

    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

    return schema;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
def createEmptyDataFrame[T: ru.TypeTag] =
    hiveContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row],
      ScalaReflection.schemaFor(ru.typeTag[T].tpe).dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
    )
  case class RawData(id: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, age: Int)
  val sourceDF = createEmptyDataFrame[RawData]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you can create schema using StructType in scala and pass the Empty RDD  so you will able to create empty table.
Following code is for the same.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.BooleanType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.LongType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType



//import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StructField

object EmptyTable extends App {
  val conf = new SparkConf;
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  //create sparksession object
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

  //Created schema for three columns 
   val schema = StructType(
    StructField("Emp_ID", LongType, true) ::
      StructField("Emp_Name", StringType, false) ::
      StructField("Emp_Salary", LongType, false) :: Nil)

      //Created Empty RDD 

  var dataRDD = sc.emptyRDD[Row]

  //pass rdd and schema to create dataframe
  val newDFSchema = sparkSession.createDataFrame(dataRDD, schema)

  newDFSchema.createOrReplaceTempView("tempSchema")

  sparkSession.sql("create table Finaltable AS select * from tempSchema")

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is helpful for testing purposes.

```
Seq.empty[String].toDF()
```

Comment: How to create empty df from trait instead :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64276952/encoders-productof-a-scala-trait-schema-in-spark

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that creates an empty dataframe in pyspark 2.0.0 or more.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = spark.sparkContext
schema = StructType([StructField('col1', StringType(),False),StructField('col2', IntegerType(), True)])
sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a special requirement wherein I already had a dataframe but given a certain condition I had to return an empty dataframe so I returned `df.limit(0)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add the following syntax which was not yet mentioned:

```scala
Seq[(String, Integer)]().toDF("k", "v")
```

It makes it clear that the `()` part is for values. It's empty, so the dataframe is empty.

This syntax is also beneficial for adding `null` values manually. It just works, while other options either don't or are overly verbose.

Answer (score 0):

We were having issues with the `emptyRDD` method after converting to Spark 13.3 / enabling Unity Catalog in Databricks. The below solution works as a replacement for both.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StringType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import java.util.ArrayList

val schema = new StructType()
  .add("column1", StringType, true)
  .add("column2", StringType, true)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  new ArrayList[Row],
  schema
)
df.count()
```

Answer (score -3):

As of Spark 2.4.3

```
val df = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate().emptyDataFrame
```

Comment: This does not solve the schema part of the question.