# How to create an empty DataFrame? Why "ValueError: RDD is empty"?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create an empty dataframe in Spark (Pyspark).

I am using similar approach to the one discussed here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477598/how-to-create-an-empty-dataframe), but it is not working.

This is my code

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/Me/Desktop/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 404, in createDataFrame
rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data, schema, samplingRatio)
File "/Users/Me/Desktop/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 285, in _createFromRDD
struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio)
File "/Users/Me/Desktop/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 229, in _inferSchema
first = rdd.first()
File "/Users/Me/Desktop/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1320, in first
raise ValueError("RDD is empty")
ValueError: RDD is empty
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

extending Joe Widen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624783/5319985), you can actually create the schema with no fields like so:

```
schema = StructType([])
```

so when you create the DataFrame using that as your schema, you'll end up with a `DataFrame[]`.

```
>>> empty = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
DataFrame[]
>>> empty.schema
StructType(List())
```

In Scala, if you choose to use `sqlContext.emptyDataFrame` and check out the schema, it will return `StructType()`.

```
scala> val empty = sqlContext.emptyDataFrame
empty: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = []

scala> empty.schema
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType()
```

Answer (score 27):

At the time this answer was written it looks like you need some sort of schema

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
field = [StructField("field1", StringType(), True)]
schema = StructType(field)

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
```

Comment: Could you provide some source proving this claim?

Comment: Looks like its not necessary actually.  Just took a look at the API information for createDataFrame and it shows the schema defaults to none, so there should be a way to create a dataframe with no schema:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Answer (score 10):

This will work with spark version 2.0.0 or more

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = spark.sparkContext
schema = StructType([StructField('col1', StringType(), False),StructField('col2', IntegerType(), True)])
sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
```

Comment: what part of this only works for 2.0 or more?  should work in 1.6.1 right @braj259?

Comment: the spark intialization part. from  2.0 onwards thereis just one spark context for everything. so intialization is syntactically little different

Comment: but if you change `sc = spark.sparkContext` to `sc = sparkContext()` then i think it should be compatible with 1.6.x right?

Answer (score 4):

```
spark.range(0).drop("id")
```

This creates a DataFrame with an "id" column and no rows then drops the "id" column, leaving you with a truly empty DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an empty dataframe based on an existing one, simple limit rows to 0.
In PySpark :

```
emptyDf = existingDf.limit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use something like this:

```
   pivot_table = sparkSession.createDataFrame([("99","99")], ["col1","col2"])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkPractice').getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
  StructField('firstname', StringType(), True),
  StructField('middlename', StringType(), True),
  StructField('lastname', StringType(), True)
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(),schema)
df.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a roundabout but simple way to create an empty spark df with an inferred schema

```
# Initialize a spark df using one row of data with the desired schema   
init_sdf = spark.createDataFrame([('a_string', 0, 0)], ['name', 'index', 'seq_#'])
# remove the row.  Leaves the schema
empty_sdf = init_sdf.where(col('name') == 'not_match')  
empty_sdf.printSchema()
# Output
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- index: long (nullable = true)
 |-- seq_#: long (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Seq.empty[String].toDF()
```

This will create a empty df. Helpful for testing purposes and all. (Scala-Spark)

Answer (score 0):

In Spark 3.1.2, the `spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD()` function throws an error. Using the `schema`, passing an empty list will work:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by loading an empty file (`parquet`, `json` etc.) like this:

```
df = sqlContext.read.json("my_empty_file.json")
```

Then when you try to check the schema you'll see:

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
```

In Scala/Java not passing a path should work too, in Python it throws an exception. Also if you ever switch to Scala/Python you can use [this method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#emptyDataFrame()) to create one.

Answer (score -2):

You can create an empty data frame by using following syntax in pyspark:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([], ["col1", "col2", ...])
```

where `[]` represents the empty value for `col1` and `col2`. Then you can register as temp view for your sql queries:

```
**df2.createOrReplaceTempView("artist")**
```

Comment: It says "Cannot infer schema from empty dataframe"