# create DataFrame of struct PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HNO6.jpg)How can I create a dataframe of empty structs please.?
Thank you .

```
dataxx = []
schema = StructType(
[
    StructField('Info1',
        StructType([
            StructField('fld', IntegerType(),True),
            StructField('fld1', IntegerType(),True),
            StructField('fld2', IntegerType(),True),
            StructField('fld3', IntegerType(),True),
            StructField('fld4', IntegerType(),True),   
            ])
    ),
]
)
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(dataxx, schema)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Not related to pandas..removed

Comment: Have you tried `spark.createDataFrame([], schema)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an empty DataFrame? Why "ValueError: RDD is empty"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624681/how-to-create-an-empty-dataframe-why-valueerror-rdd-is-empty)

Comment: @blackbishop Thank you but its not really what I mean. I want to create like this shema of data frame struct. I have added a pic to better understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create DataFrame that has specific schema but contains no data, you can do it simply by providing empty list to the `createDataFrame` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType(
[
    StructField('Info1',
        StructType([
            StructField('fld', IntegerType(),True),
            StructField('fld1', IntegerType(),True),
            StructField('fld2', IntegerType(),True),
            StructField('fld3', IntegerType(),True),
            StructField('fld4', IntegerType(),True),   
            ])
    ),
]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)

df.printSchema()

root
 |-- Info1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fld: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fld1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fld2: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fld3: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fld4: integer (nullable = true)
```

Here `spark` is sparkSession.

Comment: thank you David to add value in my fld2 for example can I do this  please. ??df.Info1.fld2 = 22

Comment: @ceo No, I am afraid it is not going to work like this. If you want to add value to info1.fld2 (and have a single row in the DataFrame) you can call `withColumn` transformation (or just `select`) and redefine the struct and in `fld2` use `lit(22)`