# scala - Spark : How to union all dataframe in loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a way to get the dataframe that union dataframe in loop?

This is a sample code:

```
var fruits = List(
  "apple"
  ,"orange"
  ,"melon"
) 

for (x <- fruits){         
  var df = Seq(("aaa","bbb",x)).toDF("aCol","bCol","name")
}
```

I would want to obtain some like this:

```
aCol | bCol | fruitsName
aaa,bbb,apple
aaa,bbb,orange
aaa,bbb,melon
```

Thanks again

Comment: What is this code ? and what are you actually trying to do here ?

Comment: This is not a union this is a cartesian product.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Steffen Schmitz's answer is the most concise one I believe. 
Below is  a more detailed answer if you are looking for more customization (of field types, etc):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

//initialize DF
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("aCol", StringType, true) ::
  StructField("bCol", StringType, true) ::
  StructField("name", StringType, true) :: Nil)
var initialDF = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schema)

//list to iterate through
var fruits = List(
    "apple"
    ,"orange"
    ,"melon"
)

for (x <- fruits) {
  //union returns a new dataset
  initialDF = initialDF.union(Seq(("aaa", "bbb", x)).toDF)
}

//initialDF.show()
```

references:

- [How to create an empty DataFrame with a specified schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477598/how-to-create-an-empty-dataframe-with-a-specified-schema/31478700)
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html
- https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/append-a-row-to-rdd-or-dataframe.html

Answer (score 27):

You could created a sequence of `DataFrame`s and then use `reduce`:

```
val results = fruits.
  map(fruit => Seq(("aaa", "bbb", fruit)).toDF("aCol","bCol","name")).
  reduce(_.union(_))

results.show()
```

Comment: simple and beautiful!

Comment: Good to see the immutable approach

Answer (score 15):

If you have different/multiple dataframes you can use below code, which is efficient.

```
val newDFs = Seq(DF1,DF2,DF3)
newDFs.reduce(_ union _)
```

Comment: how can i keep adding new dataframes to the Seq using a loop? I would like to do a union at the end, but the dataframes in my Seq are to be added using a loop. Is it doable?

Comment: Why is this efficcient? If you are applying a reduce function to a Scala Seq you are not making use of cluster paralelism and no distributed computing at all, right?

Answer (score 7):

In a for loop:

```
val fruits = List("apple", "orange", "melon")

( for(f <- fruits) yield ("aaa", "bbb", f) ).toDF("aCol", "bCol", "name")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... I think your question is a bit mis-guided.

As per my limited understanding of whatever you are trying to do, you should be doing following,

```
val fruits = List(
  "apple",
  "orange",
  "melon"
)

val df = fruits
  .map(x => ("aaa", "bbb", x))
  .toDF("aCol", "bCol", "name")
```

And this should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Sarvesh.. but I only have to get the union dataframe in Loop.. because there are various operation such as join, withColumn  in Loop . I will get the dataframe from hiveSql in Loop.

Comment: "union data-frame in loop" well... just this one statement  leaves me unable to answer this question. Why do you need this "union data-frame in loop" ? Can you elaborate in your question with more details about - "various operation such as join, withColumn in Loop".

Answer (score 1):

you can first create a sequence and then use `toDF` to create `Dataframe`.

```
scala> var dseq : Seq[(String,String,String)] = Seq[(String,String,String)]()
dseq: Seq[(String, String, String)] = List()

scala> for ( x <- fruits){
     |  dseq = dseq :+ ("aaa","bbb",x)
     | }

scala> dseq
res2: Seq[(String, String, String)] = List((aaa,bbb,apple), (aaa,bbb,orange), (aaa,bbb,melon))

scala> val df = dseq.toDF("aCol","bCol","name")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [aCol: string, bCol: string, name: string]

scala> df.show
+----+----+------+
|aCol|bCol|  name|
+----+----+------+
| aaa| bbb| apple|
| aaa| bbb|orange|
| aaa| bbb| melon|
+----+----+------+
```

Comment: And why did you feel the need to introduce a `var` here ?

Comment: actually  what i tried was to a create a `Seq` and convert it to dataframe, since i'm iterating through the list of fruit and appending it into a same variable, so i have taken it as `var`.

Comment: The OP has used `var` but he did not actually need it. And, you could have just `mapped` the `fruits` into your `dseq`. The important thing to note here is that your `dseq` is a `List`. And then you are appending to this list in your `for` "loop". The problem with this is that `append` on `List` is `O(n)` making your whole `dseq` generation `O(n^2)`, which will just kill performance on large data.

Comment: Just make it a general principle to avoid `append` with Scala `List`.

Comment: Thanks @SarveshKumarSingh.