# Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, union

This is my code for the union:

```
val dfToSave=dfMainOutput.union(insertdf.select(dfMainOutput).withColumn("FFAction", when($"FFAction" === "O" || $"FFAction" === "I", lit("I|!|")))
```

When I do union I get below error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. string <> boolean at the 11th column of the second table;;
'Union
```

Here is the schema of two dataframes:

```
insertdf.printSchema()
root
 |-- OrganizationID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- SourceID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorOpinionCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsPlayingAuditorRole: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsPlayingTaxAdvisorRole: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorEnumerationId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorOpinionId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlsId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsPlayingCSRAuditorRole: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- FFAction: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DataPartition: string (nullable = true)
```

Here is the schema of second dataframe:

```
dfMainOutput.printSchema()
root
 |-- OrganizationID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- SourceID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorOpinionCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsPlayingAuditorRole: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsPlayingTaxAdvisorRole: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorEnumerationId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorOpinionId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlsId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernId: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsPlayingCSRAuditorRole: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FFAction: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DataPartition: string (nullable = true)
```

To avoid this problem I might have to write a `select` for each columns.
So is there any Scala syntax that manage to type caste or make both dataframes to same type?

This is what I have tried so far but still getting the same error:

```
val columns = dfMainOutput.columns.toSet.intersect(insertdf.columns.toSet).map(col).toSeq

//Perform Union
val dfToSave=dfMainOutput.select(columns: _*).union(insertdf.select(columns: _*)).withColumn("FFAction", when($"FFAction" === "O" || $"FFAction" === "I", lit("I|!|")))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **datatypes of each column must match** to perform an union of dataframes.

Looking at your schemas, there are three columns that does not conform to this:

```
AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlsId
AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernId
IsPlayingCSRAuditorRole
```

An easy way to change the data types would be to use `withColumn` and `cast`. I'm assuming the correct type is in the `dfMainOutput` dataframe for the code below:

```
val insertDfNew = insertdf
  .withColumn("AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlsId", $"AuditorOpinionOnInternalControlsId".cast(IntegerType))
  .withColumn("AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernId", $"AuditorOpinionOnGoingConcernId".cast(BooleanType))
  .withColumn("IsPlayingCSRAuditorRole", $"IsPlayingCSRAuditorRole".cast(StringType))
  .withColumn("FFAction", when($"FFAction" === "O" || $"FFAction" === "I", lit("I|!|")).otherwise($"FFAction"))

val dfToSave = dfMainOutput.union(insertDfNew)
```

Comment: Also, you can cast in the following way df.select(col("value").cast("string"))

Comment: @BdEngineer: Sure, you can do that. If you have a list of dataframes that you want to union into a single one, then you can do: `dataframeList.reduce(_.union(_))`. It can also be done iterativly inside a for-loop if you calculate them one-by-one, but then you need to have a start dataframe or create an empty dataframe with the correct schema.

Comment: @BdEngineer: I'm not sure if there are any performance differences but I think it shold be pretty similar. I found this question where the first two answers shows what I wrote in the comment above (a bit clearer with actual examples): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43489807/scala-spark-how-to-union-all-dataframe-in-loop Note that the dataframe you union into needs to be a `var` (it can change) and not a `val`.

Comment: @BdEngineer: I'm not sure what the problem can be. Maybe you can create a new question with the code, hopefully I or someone else can spot what is going wrong.