# Scala: How to combine two data frames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

First Df is:

```
ID Name ID2 Marks
1   12    1   333
```

Second Df2 is:

```
ID Name ID2 Marks
1         3   989
7   98    8   878
```

I need output is:

```
ID Name ID2 Marks
1   12    1   333
1         3   989
7   98    8   878
```

Kindly help!

Comment: What do you have so far? Just an assignment?

Comment: Look Here ..
[val newDFs = Seq(DF1,DF2,DF3)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52115838/3511957)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `union` or `unionAll` function:

```
df1.unionAll(df2)
df1.union(df2)
```

for example:

```
scala> val a = (1,"12",1,333)
a: (Int, String, Int, Int) = (1,12,1,333)

scala> val b = (1,"",3,989)
b: (Int, String, Int, Int) = (1,"",3,989)

scala> val c = (7,"98",8,878)
c: (Int, String, Int, Int) = (7,98,8,878)

scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> val df1 = List(a).toDF("ID","Name","ID2","Marks")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: int, Name: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> val df2 = List(b, c).toDF("ID","Name","ID2","Marks")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: int, Name: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> df1.show
+---+----+---+-----+
| ID|Name|ID2|Marks|
+---+----+---+-----+
|  1|  12|  1|  333|
+---+----+---+-----+


scala> df2.show
+---+----+---+-----+
| ID|Name|ID2|Marks|
+---+----+---+-----+
|  1|    |  3|  989|
|  7|  98|  8|  878|
+---+----+---+-----+


scala> df1.union(df2).show
+---+----+---+-----+
| ID|Name|ID2|Marks|
+---+----+---+-----+
|  1|  12|  1|  333|
|  1|    |  3|  989|
|  7|  98|  8|  878|
+---+----+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `union` or `unionAll` should do the trick for you

```
Df.union(Df2)
```

or

```
Df.unionAll(Df2)
```

As given in the api document

> > Returns a new Dataset containing union of rows in this Dataset and another Dataset.
> >       This is equivalent to `UNION ALL` in SQL. To do a SQL-style set union (that does
> >       deduplication of elements), use this function followed by a [[distinct]].
> >       Also as standard in SQL, this function resolves columns by position (not by name).