# Create an empty DataFrame with specified schema without SparkContext with SparkSession

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is different from [How to create an empty DataFrame with a specified schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477598/how-to-create-an-empty-dataframe-with-a-specified-schema)

The difference is I am asking "**without SparkContext**". The reason I ask this requirement is

> Since Spark 2.x.x, All three data abstractions are unified and 
>   SparkSession is the unified entry point of Spark.

If they are all unified, can we create an empty DataFrame with specified schema without `SparkContext` (with `SparkSession` only)

Basically, I am looking for something like `SparkSession.createDataFrame`.

Comment: The first two answers in the linked question seems to cover some of the ways to do it. For example `spark.emptyDataset[Person]` won't use `SparkContext`. (by the way, `SparkContext` is accessible through `SparkSession` by using `spark.sparkContext`.)

Comment: @shaido Yes, it is accessible, but creatDataframe is not accessible in `spark.sparkContext`

Comment: @JohnHass it should be accessable through `spark.createDataframe`.

Comment: @Shaido I ask this question, because `spark.createDataframe` does not provide `createDataframe`.