# How do I avoid/fix error "java.io.Serializable" in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do you typically fix the "java.io.Serializable" error below?

I am guessing the data types in my functions caused it (?). How do you avoid it OR change the result back to the right type.

```
def allKeys(sampledf: DataFrame): DataFrame = {......}

val afd12= afd.schema.fieldNames.contains("ID") && afd.schema.fieldNames.contains("CONNECTIDS") match {
   case true => allKeys(afd) 
   case false => "no"
}

afd12.printSchema()
```

This is the error I get:

```
afd: java.io.Serializable = [ID: string, ADDITIONALINFO: string ... 87 more fields]
<console>:95: error: value printSchema is not a member of java.io.Serializable
   afd12.printSchema()
         ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make sure that pattern match block

```
 match {
   case true => allKeys(afd) 
   case false => "no"
}
```

returns consistent types. Right now one branch returns `Dataset[Row]` and another `String`, so the closest common type is `Serializable`. The simplest fix is to return an [empty `DataFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31477598) with schema of your choice, instead of `no`.

```
match {
  case true => allKeys(afd) 
  case _ => spark.emptyDataFrame
}
```